# What is this Shape Key Icon referencing?

Tags: shape-keys, outliner

What is this Shape Key Icon referencing in the Outliner?  Is it the name for the Shape Key data set?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon shows that there are shapekeys on that object. The name is normally set to `Key` with a number suffix if that is already in use, but can be renamed.

In the outliner you can double click the name to change it.

From python you can use `bpy.data.shape_keys["Hide.001"].name = "NewName"`

Comment: Thank you sambler for the answer and the extra python info!  Would up vote this answer, but I'm not at 15 rep points yet.